# leaderboard not show when login a new user in android

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm integrating Google play games service to my app and I implemented `BaseGameActivity`, but when I log in a new user the leaderboard is not showing.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
            .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
            .build();
```

**show leadrboard**

```
startActivityForResult(
    Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getGameHelper().getApiClient(),
    getString(R.string.leaderboard_bxh)), 0);
```

Comment: You need to show your code and provide more information, if you need any help

Comment: ` mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .setViewForPopups(findViewById(android.R.id.content))
                .build();`

Comment: I use this code above, help me

Comment: can I login, but can't show leaderboard when login a new user

Comment: can you also show the onConnectionCallbacks listener code

Comment: NoodDogg- I not use onConnectionCallbacksListenner, how to do???

Comment: When I login leaderboard is show, but after gameover then leaderboad not working

Comment: Have you checked the [Displaying a Leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards#displaying_a_leaderboard) guide?